# PHPExcel Data Bars

Tags: phpexcel

I have in my Excel file in Cells A1:A5 date in percent and I would like to put in these cells data bars with gradient fills. I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

To get a gradient fill background:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:C3')->applyFromArray(
        array(
            'fill' => array(
                'type'       => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_GRADIENT_LINEAR,
                'rotation'   => 90,
                'startcolor' => array(
                    'argb' => 'FFFF0000'
                ),
                'endcolor'   => array(
                    'argb' => 'FF0000FF'
                )
            )
        )
);
```

If you want gradient fill lines across the cell to the level of percentage, that feature isn't supported by PHPExcel.

Comment: Thank you Mark, so it is impossible to fill the cell background only half when it is half the value in another cell than? For example, the value in A1 is 100 and in A2 is 50, so that the entire background A1 and A2 only half?

Comment: Correct, PHPExcel doesn't support this feature